# App breaks when I add firebase to list of app dependencies

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to initialize an angular app with angularfire. I'm using yeoman's angular generator to create a new angular scaffold. Then, I'm adding the the firebase and angularfire CDNs:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

And lastly, I'm adding firebase as a dependency to the app module:

```
angular
  .module('socialfictionApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'firebase'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

But when I spin up the application with grunt the app breaks -- views don't render, the navigation breaks, etc. But as soon as I remove the `firebase` dependency from the app module everything works fine.

**EDIT**

In my console I get the following errors:

Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined > cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js:7

Uncaught object localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3809

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Do you include `angular.js` before the `angularfire.js`?

Comment: You might want to post that as an answer @runTarm

Comment: Arg. That was the problem. I had to include firebase before the closing html tag. Post this as an answer and I'll confirm. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that it fully solve the problem :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to include the `angularfire.min.js` script tag **AFTER** the one for `angular.js`:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried yeoman generator with bower and i had to add this in terminal

`bower install angularfire --save`.

I have found it in example provided by thinkster.io chapter 4 of tutorial Learn to Build Modern Web Apps with the AngularJS Tutorial

Comment: That's interesting. I tried installing angularfire with bower and the application wouldn't work either. I'll try this method.